# Interstitial ad taking taking upwards of 5 minutes to load

Tags: admob, coronasdk

I give up. I've been trying literally all day to get an interstitial ad to load within a reasonable amount of time when switching over to a specific scene I've created in composer to show ads. I must be doing something inherently wrong... because I can't find much documentation regarding using composer with interstitial ads in which my best guess is that almost nobody is having issues with it.

Anyway... here is my source code. If you see anything blatantly wrong with it, please let me know... Either way, thanks for reading.

```
            local composer = require( "composer" )

            local scene = composer.newScene()

            -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            -- All code outside of the listener functions will only be executed ONCE unless "composer.removeScene()" is called.
            -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            -- local forward references should go here
            centerX = display.contentCenterX
            centerY = display.contentCenterY
            screenLeft = display.screenOriginX
            screenWidth = display.contentWidth - screenLeft * 2
            screenRight = screenLeft + screenWidth
            screenTop = display.screenOriginY
            screenHeight = display.contentHeight - screenTop * 2
            screenBottom = screenTop + screenHeight
            display.contentWidth = screenWidth
            display.contentHeight = screenHeight
            display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
            local ads = require( "ads" )
            local interstitialAppID = "ca-app-pub-6798972966452738/6428249200"
            local adProvider = "admob"
            ads.init( adProvider, interstitialAppID, adListener )


            local options =
            {
                effect = "zoomInOutFade",
                time = 600,
            }

            -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            local function adListener( event )
                if ( event.isError ) then
                    ads.load("interstitial", {appID = interstitialAppID})
                    -- attempt to fetch another ad
                elseif ( event.phase == "loaded" ) then
                    ads.show("interstitial", {appID = interstitialAppID})
                    -- an ad was preloaded
                elseif (event.phase ~= "loaded") then 
                    composer.gotoScene("levelSelect", options)
                elseif ( event.phase == "shown" ) then
                    composer.gotoScene("levelSelect", options)
                end
            end
            -- "scene:create()"
            function scene:create( event )

                local sceneGroup = self.view


                -- Initialize the scene here.
                -- Example: add display objects to "sceneGroup", add touch listeners, etc.
            end


            -- "scene:show()"
            function scene:show( event )

                local sceneGroup = self.view
                local phase = event.phase

                if ( phase == "will" ) then

                    -- Called when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen).
                elseif ( phase == "did" ) then

                    -- Called when the scene is now on screen.
                    -- Insert code here to make the scene come alive.
                    -- Example: start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
                end
            end


            -- "scene:hide()"
            function scene:hide( event )

                local sceneGroup = self.view
                local phase = event.phase

                if ( phase == "will" ) then
                    -- Called when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen).
                    -- Insert code here to "pause" the scene.
                    -- Example: stop timers, stop animation, stop audio, etc.
                elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
                    ads.load("interstitial", {appID = interstitialAppID})
                    -- Called immediately after scene goes off screen.
                end
            end


            -- "scene:destroy()"
            function scene:destroy( event )

                local sceneGroup = self.view

                -- Called prior to the removal of scene's view ("sceneGroup").
                -- Insert code here to clean up the scene.
                -- Example: remove display objects, save state, etc.
            end


            -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            -- Listener setup
            scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
            scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
            scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
            scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )

            -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            return scene
```

Answer (score 1):

Interstitials some do take a long time load.

The standard flow is to load the interstitial when your Activity starts and then at a natural break point in your app, check to see if it has loaded, if so, show it.

Attempting to show the interstitial as soon as it is loaded (using a listener) is a really bad idea. It provides a really poor user experience and Admob have made it clear that it is against their policy and will get your account banned.

Comment: When using composer can I start loading from the very first scene though? Ive tried that and it didnt seem to help any. The way my game is set up... Opening scene, level select, gameplay, win or lose screen, ad screen, back to level select. If I run ads.load in the opening scene and then ads.show in the ad screen it doesnt do anything. Is this because composer flushes the ads.load? If so... Is there a work around?

Comment: I can't answer that. I have never used Corona and they are Corona specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for your time either way. I figured it out for any curious and/or googling this same issue. I put my ads.init, and ads listener function in my main.lua. Where ever you want to show an ad, use an if(ads.isLoaded() then ads.show.